# Creating empty entity on a OneToOne-relation in Symfony

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, one-to-one

I'm running a Symfony 2.4 project with Doctrine 2.4 and having some issues with form creation/validation.

I have an entity "Person" with a **OneToOne-Relation** to an "Address" entity (unidirectional) - so the person can have one or none addresses.

```
/**
 * @var Address
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Koala\AddressBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"all"})
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
private $address;
public function setAddress(Address $address = null)
{
    $this->address = $address;
}
```

In my PersonType class for the form rendering I have added the code as follows:

```
$builder->add('address', AddressType::SERVICE_NAME,
    array(
        'label' => 'address._label',
        'required' => false
    )
);
```

Loading/Displaying a Person-entity that doesn't have an Address works fine - i.e. no fields are shown for the address because in my Twig-template I have:

```
{% if form.address.vars.value|default is not empty %}  
    {# address form here #}
{% endif %}
```

Also loading the edit form works fine, i.e. no address form is shown, as I don't want to have an address in that place of the App (but in general Person could have an address).

The problem now is, as soon as I change something in the persons form and submit the changes to the server, form validation fails because Symfony creates a new empty Address object for which the validation fails because there are some mandatory fields in an Address. But here I explicitly don't want an address.
I thought that having the if-condition (see above) should solve this. Because using two different twig-templates that quite look the same - just one not having an address seemed ugly to me and would violate the [DRY-Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY_principle).

What am I doing wrong?
How can I stop Symfony from creating an empty Address-object for a person?

**EDIT:**
For better clarification, here the code of the controller method handling edit:

```
public function editAction($id, $version, Request $request) {
    try {
        $company = $this->companyRepository->find($id, LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, $version);
        $routeId = array('id' => $id, 'version' => $company->getVersion());
        $form = $this->createForm(CompanyType::SERVICE_NAME, $company, array(
            'action' => $this->router->generate('replaced_for_stackoverflow', $routeId),
             'method' => 'POST')
        );

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) { 
                // If isValid() were true, entity changes would get saved.
            }
            // But: isValid() is false, because there is an Address-Entity in one of the Person-entities attached to the company-entity. And this is because Symfony creates an Address-Instance by itself. And I don't know how to turn this behavior off.
        }
    }
    // Rest of method left out as irrelevant to the problem.
}
```

Comment: It might help if you posted the error message. Have you tried `entity->setAddress()` before persist in your controller updateAction?

Comment: The error message is that validation of Address-Entity fails because two fields in the Address-Entity are empty. But I don't want any Address-Entity at all - unless I create one explicitly. I don't want Symfony to create an empty Address-Entity for me. I'm not persisting yet - the error is before. I updated the question above with some controller code - hope that clarifies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cascade in the property address annotation::

```
/**
* @var Address
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Koala\AddressBundle\Entity\Address")
* @Assert\Valid
*/
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem - an Address entity is still created when trying to save changes.